# Force close when trying to open activity plus display data from database in Spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I'm having issues with an SQLite Database. I get force close messages when I tried to open my activity. It has a spinner which displays data from a database table. I can open the activity and the spinner displays the data from the table, following this example - [Android: populate a Spinner from a SQLite database - SamColes](http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-populate-a-spinner-from-your-sqlite-database/).

Here is my code and LogCat.

AnniversaryAdapter - 5 tables created

```
public class AnniversaryDBAdapter
{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Tables";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

     private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TITLE = "create table titles(title_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, image text not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST = "create table buddiesList(name_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LIKES = "create table likes(likes_id integer primary key autoincrement,like text not null, name_id integer not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DISLIKES = "create table dislikes(dlike_id integer primary key autoincrement, dislike text not null, name_id integer not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS = "create table event(event_id integer primary key autoincrement, title_id integer not null, location text not null, starttime text not null, endtime text not null, desc text not null, date text not null, name_id integer not null);";

    private final Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/main.page/Tables/";


    public AnniversaryDBAdapter(Context aContext)
    {
        this.context = aContext;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }




private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        /*try
        {
            database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST);
            database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LIKES);
            database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS);
            database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TITLE);
            database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DISLIKES);
        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LIKES);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TITLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DISLIKES);
/*      database.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER fk_budevent_nameid" +
                "BEFORE INSERT" +
                "ON events FOR EACH ROW BEGIN" +
                "SELECT CASE WHEN((SELECT name_id FROM buddiesList WHERE name_id = new.name_id) IS NULL)" +
                "THEN RAISE(ABORT, 'Foreign Key Violation')END;" +
                "END;");
        */


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version "+oldVersion+" to "+newVersion+", which will destroy all old data");

        onCreate(db);

    }

}


public AnniversaryDBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = this.DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
/*  if(!db.isReadOnly())
    {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    }*/
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}
/*
public long insertEvent(String title,String location,String starttime,String endtime,String desc,String date, String name)
{
   ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();



   cValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
   cValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
   cValues.put(KEY_START, starttime);
   cValues.put(KEY_END, endtime);
   cValues.put(KEY_DESC, desc);
   cValues.put(KEY_ALARM, alarm);
   cValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
   cValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);


   return db.insert(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS, null, cValues);

}

public boolean deleteEvent(long rowId)
{
    return db.delete(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public Cursor getAllEvents()
{
    return db.query(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_START, KEY_END, KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE, KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);

}

public Cursor getEvent(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor c = db.query(true,CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_START, KEY_END, KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE, KEY_NAME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
*/
}
```

BuddyDBAdapter - buddiesList table

```
 public class BuddyDBAdapter extends AnniversaryDBAdapter
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "name_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST = "buddiesList";

    //private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public BuddyDBAdapter(Context aContext)
    {
        super(aContext);
    }

    public long insertNames(String name)
    {
        ContentValues buddyValues = new ContentValues();
        buddyValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        return db.insert(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, null, buddyValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteNames(long rowId)
    {
        return db.delete(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllNames()
    {

           return db.query(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null);


    }

    public Cursor getNames(long rowId) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor c = db.query(true, CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c != null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

PersonalInformation.class

Code for displaying data from database table into the spinner and insert the data into likes table and dislikes table.

```
BuddyDBAdapter buddyDB = new BuddyDBAdapter(this);
        buddyDB.open();

        sendTo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sendTo);
        Cursor friendsCursor = buddyDB.getAllNames();
        startManagingCursor(friendsCursor);

        String[] from = new String[]{BuddyDBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.to};

        SimpleCursorAdapter friendsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, friendsCursor, from, to);
        friendsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sendTo.setAdapter(friendsAdapter);

        sendTo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
                {
                    Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                    namesSpinnderId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BuddyDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID));                  
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
        buddyDB.close();
```

LogCat

```
09-26 15:43:42.188: I/dalvikvm(658): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-26 15:43:42.198: I/dalvikvm(658): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-26 15:43:42.578: D/gralloc_goldfish(658): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-26 15:43:45.288: D/AndroidRuntime(658): Shutting down VM
09-26 15:43:45.288: W/dalvikvm(658): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{main.page/main.page.PersonalInformation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at main.page.AnniversaryDBAdapter.open(AnniversaryDBAdapter.java:96)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at main.page.PersonalInformation.onCreate(PersonalInformation.java:55)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-26 15:43:45.308: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  ... 11 more
```

I do not want to change any code in any of database adapters because I modified

```
return db.delete(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
```

to

```
if(db != null)
  return db.query(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null);
return null;
```

in `getAllNames()` in BuddyDBAdapter which caused major problems. Plus, I've tried it and it can open the activity but no data is displayed in the spinner and none of the tables were created in the database browser.

Comment: you have to add the "_id" column to be able to use CursorAdapter, for the Logcut update, the DBHelper is not initialized, i think that you have passed a null context to it. Please insure that your are removing all db when you change the DataBase.

Comment: why your are closing the data base at this stage? buddyDB.close();
must be called from on Destroy before killing your activity

Comment: i thought it should usually open and close the database. and i don't want to kill my activity and do not have onDestroy method in any of my classes. plus I think i should initialize DBHelper like this `private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;` & `DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);` in AnnivesaryDBAdapter which I've done so?

Comment: when you are displaying the List on spinner DB must be opened. make a call to super @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (this.getWritableDatabase() != null)
            this.getWritableDatabase().close();
        super.close();
    }

Comment: Do you mean I need to call `if (this.getWritableDatabase() != null) this.getWritableDatabase().close(); super.close();` in `public void close()` in AnniversaryDBAdapter?

Comment: yes you need that, also you need to not close the data base where you are showing your spinner.

Answer (score 0):

see 09-26 15:15:22.152: E/AndroidRuntime(574): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist in your logcat ad this to your tables

you buddydb open function gives a java.lang.NullPointerException
I do not now why u use this function as it is not needed by the SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. there is update in the LogCat. Please look at it in my post. sorry and thanks.

Comment: you buddydb open function gives a java.lang.NullPointerException I do not now why u use this function as it is not needed by the SQLiteOpenHelper

Answer (score 0):

The `SimpleCursorAdapter` needs an `attribute _id` on the cursor, to fix this problem just change your data base like this:

```
  private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TITLE = "create table titles(_id integer, title_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, image text not null);";
            private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST = "create table buddiesList(_id integer, name_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null);";
            private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LIKES = "create table likes(_id integer, likes_id integer primary key autoincrement,like text not null, name_id integer not null);";
            private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DISLIKES = "create table dislikes(_id integer, dlike_id integer primary key autoincrement, dislike text not null, name_id integer not null);";
            private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS = "create table event(_id integer, event_id integer primary key autoincrement, title_id integer not null, location text not null, 
            starttime text not null, endtime text not null, desc text not null,date text not null, name_id integer not null);";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Uh, I've tried to run my app and tried open the activity again, and there is update in the LogCat. Please look at the updated LogCat in my post. sorry and thanks.